Remove "(chairman)" when using sapthesis
I'm using the sapthesis package. It allows for indicating multiple examiners via the command \examiner (e.g. \examiner{Jon Doe}). If at least one examiner is indicated, after the first one it appends the string  (chairman).

Since I don't have a chairman, I need to get rid of that string.
This is a minimal reproducible example:
\documentclass[a4paper,english,binding=0.6cm]{sapthesis}

\newcommand{\thesistitle}{XYZ}
\newcommand{\myname}{XXX}
\title{\thesistitle}
\author{\myname}
\IDnumber{XXX}
\course{XXX}
\courseorganizer{XXX}
\AcademicYear{XXX}
\advisor{XXX}
\authoremail{X@Y}
\copyyear{XXX}

\examdate{MY DATE}
\examiner{Jon Doe}
\examiner{Mary Smith}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \maketitle
    \mainmatter
\end{document}


In LaTeX every command can always be modified from the document itself, also when it belongs to a library, or even when it is part of basic LaTeX. So if you can present your actual use case then we can show you how to do the modification.

IMHO it is unclear, what you want, maybe \renewcommand*{\myCommand}[1]{#1} or maybe \renewcommand*{\myCommand}[1]{#1 \hphantom{(bar)}} or maybe something completely different. Please show a minimal working example of what you are currently using and use this also to explain the requested difference as exact as possible, e.g., fake the requested result with other code.

@Marijn@cabohah Thank you for the instructions. I have updated the question with the real example.

Thanks for the edit, it is getting a bit more clear now. To clarify further and to save time from potential answerers it would help if you provide a complete but minimal example document (called MWE, Minimal Working Example) that can be compiled as it is and that shows the issue. If you can add this to your post you will have a much better chance of getting the issue resolved.

Code should always be added as text to the question and not as a screenshot, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors.

@Marijn   Done! Thanks

You can look up the original definition in sapthesis.cls, for example on https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sapthesis or in your local LaTeX installation directory. On line 320 we find the following code:
\newcommand{\examiner}[2][]{% 
  \ifnum\SAP@examinercount=\z@ 
    \SAP@examinertoks={#2 (\SAP@chairman\if|#1|\relax\else, #1\fi)}% 
  \else 
    \SAP@examinertoks=\expandafter{\the\SAP@examinertoks\\[0.75mm]#2 \if|#1|\relax\else (#1)\fi}% 
  \fi 
  \advance\SAP@examinercount\@ne}

You can see the ifnum-else construct: if the current examiner counter is zero (\z@) then print (chairman).
To simplify you can remove the whole if-else and leave the body of the else as default.
To put this change in your document you will need \renewcommand instead of \newcommand, otherwise you will get an error that the command you try to define already exists.
Furthermore, because there are @ symbols in the command definition, you need \makeatletter and \makeatother around the redefinition.
Code:
\documentclass[a4paper,english,binding=0.6cm]{sapthesis}

\newcommand{\thesistitle}{XYZ}
\newcommand{\myname}{XXX}
\title{\thesistitle}
\author{\myname}
\IDnumber{XXX}
\course{XXX}
\courseorganizer{XXX}
\AcademicYear{XXX}
\advisor{XXX}
\authoremail{X@Y}
\copyyear{XXX}

% adapted from original definition at sapthesis.cls line 320
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\examiner}[2][]{% 
  \SAP@examinertoks=\expandafter{\the\SAP@examinertoks\\[0.75mm]#2 \if|#1|\relax\else (#1)\fi}% 
\advance\SAP@examinercount\@ne}
\makeatother

\examdate{MY DATE}
\examiner{Jon Doe}
\examiner{Mary Smith}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \maketitle
    \mainmatter
\end{document}

Result:

